# OnPaint Event свой компонент

Tags: c#, winforms, paintevent

Подскажите как в своем компоненте через событие OnPaint передать, что надо рисовать на PictureBox который находится на моем компоненте, а не на всем?

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Подозреваю, что нужен виртуальный метод в PictureBox для последующего переопределения, или я не прав?

Comment: Извиняюсь, не уточнил. Это winforms.

Comment: Если нужно рисовать на PictureBox, то именно этот ПикчаБокс подпишите на событие Paint. Или перегрузите метод OnPaint этого PB.